# Create thread is not accepting the member function

Tags: c++, windows, callback, function-pointers

I am trying to create a class for network programming. This will create a general purpose socket with thread.

But when I tried to crete the thread using createthread(). The third argument is producing errors. And from the net I came to know that I can't use the member functions as an argument to the createthread().

Is there any thing by which I can achieve this?

Comment: The problem is that a "member function" is actually two things: a pointer to the function, and a pointer to the instance to apply it to.  C++ can't turn that into just a function pointer (well, it could, but it doesn't try hard enough).

Comment: "doesn't try hard enough"? And how exactly do you propose it'd do that? It is generally speaking pretty hard to pack two words of data into one word of storage, and that's without even considering the other problem, that member functions and non-members have different calling conventions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At lost I got it, the very fact is, in **CreateThread** if you pass the **socket** then there is no trouble. Because **CreateThread** is **taking care** of that **socket**. But if you pass as an object which is having that **socket**, then **CreateThread** is **not taking care** of the **socket**, and it is ends up in **invalid socket** in the **new thread**.

The successed code below

```
SOCKET s=socket(....);
bind(s,...);
listen(s,...);
SOCKET temp=accept(s,(sockaddr *)&addrNew,&size);
DWORD threadId;
HANDLE thread=CreateThread(NULL,0,&MyThreadFunction,(LPVOID)(temp),0,&threadId);
```

Comment: There is no reason that passing an object pointer which contains the socket as a member variable wouldn't work.  If the socket variable became invalid, it is due to some coding error on your part.  CreateThread has no concept of sockets, or how to "take care" of them.

Comment: I don't think so. I am examining this for nearly two weeks. You can check it. My assumption is socket needs some environment, and when you are paasing it through CreateThread, createthread passes the environment also. But if you juat pass a object(which is having that socket), then in thread it is invalid. I checked it. And MSDN forum also showing examples as passing socket in createthread. It seems they are hiding some minus point of createthread.

Comment: The explanation is completely incorrect; see Brook Miles' response. -1 for this.

Comment: @michael Whatever you asked has been done by me 4 years back(see the date on my comment). And I posted the code also. I would be happy if you pointed out the problem in the code.

Comment: @prabhakaran `CreateThread` doesn't know what a `SOCKET` is. It doesn't care. In your answer you stated "Because CreateThread is taking care of that socket." which is incorrect. What you probably meant or should have meant really is that when you pass the socket as the state parameter to `CreateThread`, the body of the callback is taking care of that socket. If you pass anything other than a `SOCKET` and you cast to `SOCKET` in the callback, it will probably generate an access violation error.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. Now I am getting some light. As you said it might be a casting issue.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way to handle this is to create a "stub" function which calls back into your class.

```
UINT tid
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, myThreadStub, this, 0, &tid);

....

unsigned long WINAPI myThreadStub(void *ptr) 
{
    if (!ptr) return -1;
    return ((MyClass*)ptr)->ThreadMain();
}
```

CreateThread() allows you to pass an argument to the thread function (parameter 4 of the CreateThread() call).  You can use this to pass a pointer to your class.  You can then have the thread stub cast that pointer back into the proper type and then call a member function.  You can even have "myThreadStub" be a *static* member of "MyClass", allowing it 
to access private members and data.

If you have boost installed, you may be able to use boost::bind to do this without creating a stub function.  I've never tried that on windows, so I can't say for sure it would work (because the callback function must be a WINAPI call) but if it does work it would look something like:

```
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, boost::bind(&MyClass::ThreadFunction, this), NULL, 0, &tid);
```

Where thread function is a non-static member function which takes a single void * argument.

Comment: Use the "1010" button, or just indent 4 spaces.

Comment: Boost.Bind doesn't help here - it returns functors, not function pointers.

Answer (score 5):

There's an easy way to solve the problem.

Take a look at [ThreadProc callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736.aspx):

```
    DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(
      __in  LPVOID lpParameter
    );
```

And now at [CreateThread function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx):

```
    HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(
      __in_opt   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
      __in       SIZE_T dwStackSize,
      __in       LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
      __in_opt   LPVOID lpParameter,
      __in       DWORD dwCreationFlags,
      __out_opt  LPDWORD lpThreadId
    );
```

Use a static method as thread procedure, but call it from a member method, and pass the object pointer to it:

```
    #include <windows.h>

    class MyClass {
     public:
      void CreateThreadForObject() {
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security_attributes = 0;
        SIZE_T stack_size = 0;
        LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE start_routine = &MyClass::ThreadProcForObject;
        LPVOID param = this;
        DWORD creation_flags = 0;
        LPDWORD thread_id = 0;
        CreateThread(security_attributes, stack_size, start_routine, param,
                     creation_flags, thread_id);
      }

     private:
      static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProcForObject(LPVOID param) {
        MyClass* instance = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(param);
        if (!instance) return 1;
        // ...
        return 0;
      }
    };
```

Sorry, I just don't have enough time to write a good example. But I think you understand the way.

Comment: I would mark this +10. This the first method I found which not reveals class internals to public. I am C# dev and C# does such fun stuff for me.

Comment: may be you if know, can do the same with lambda?