# C++ and member function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers, member

I'm trying to send an address of a member function to my "Thread" class so I can activate it from there.
I read that I can use functors but I want it to be generic in a way that I can send it to my "Thread" constructor and functors need templates, so it won't be enough for me...

Does anybody know a way to do this?
thanks :)

Comment: Which "Thread" class are you using? Is it one of the boost library classes? Some other library? Did you roll your own? If you have your own class, you should at least post the header definition of that class. Otherwise, people will not be able to give you very good advice.

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail. Which thread library are you using ?

Comment: Why not use an existing library? You will not write anything more generic than `std::thread` or `boost::thread` combined with `boost::bind`, and chances are that you will have bugs that are less probable in prepacked libraries.

Comment: I was thinking of writing my own "Thread" class, I can't find the "thread.h" header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use a stub function as suggested in this thread:
[Create thread is not accepting the member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891926/create-thread-is-not-accepting-the-member-functon)
thanks everbody :)

Answer (score 2):

If I may suggest a different approach: derive from your thread class and make a virtual Run() function.

The reason is that although it is possible to call a function pointer from the static thread entry function, you face problem after problem. For example, you can solve the problem of having the right function signature with templates and variadic parameters, but it is not of much avail, because the entry function won't know *what* to send to your function.

On the other hand, deriving from Thread is easy and straightforward. You put into the contructor whatever the thread needs to know. Or, optionally, you can call any number of other functions and set any number of members before you create the thread. Once you do create the thread, the static thread entry function will simply call the virtual Run function. Now... the Run function is part of the thread object, so it knows anything the class knows -- no problem.

The extra overhead of a single virtual function call and of one pointer in the vtable is also ridiculously small compared to how easy it is.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the treatment of this topic in the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html). In short, pointers to member functions are problematic, but there are several work-arounds, as well as a number of reasons why they should be avoided for certain purposes.